# How to compile vuejs for dynamic modules using PHP without node installed locally

Tags: php, laravel, webpack, vuejs2

I am trying to achieve dynamic modules for vuejs, if the user copy paste a vuex module it should be included dynamically without uses having to run npm run production/build. I want to encapsulate this in the backend layer so that if user if installing a module from UI then php can take care of it and no need to run production for vue

I am able to setup dynamic modules but only after build it will be included in the bundled file

```php
var App = {
      modules: [
          'roles','admin'
      ]
    };

App.modules.forEach((module) => {
    var dynamicModule = require(`./dynamic/${module}/index.js`);
    console.log(dynamicModule);
});
```

What i am getting is the compiled modules from dynamic folder after building, but i want to include modules after build dynamically.